# Convert TIME to INT in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

One of my columns is coming up as a TIME type but I would like it to come up as an INT type because the values aren't translating well in Tableau.

I tried running the CAST function like so:

```
CAST(ride_length AS INT) AS ride_length,
```

Someone in a previous question suggested the following:

```
SELECT (DATEPART(hour, Col1) * 3600) + (DATEPART(minute, Col1) * 60) + DATEPART(second, Col1) as SecondsFromMidnight FROM T1;
```

DATEPART does not work in BigQuery and I don't see a DATE function that would work on the documentation.

Comment: You can use the `EXTRACT` function: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract

Comment: There is no MINUTE_SECOND function so I was only able to separate the minutes and seconds into separate columns:                                                           
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ride_length) AS ride_length_min,
  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ride_length) AS ride_length_sec,                                         Is it possble to combine the two into a FLOAT?

Answer (score 0):

Converting a `TIME` to seconds:

```sql
SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME(ride_length)) * 3600) + (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIME(ride_length))  * 60) + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME(ride_length)) as SecondsFromMidnight FROM T1;
```

More info: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#extract